# Google Map API rows limit

Tags: google-maps

I am adding near 100 rows to a Google Map using the Map Visualization API.

It renders correctly but keeps showing me the tag "some of the data rows were truncated" and only 400 rows (locations) are added to the map.

How can i add more elements to my map?

Comment: Found my answer in changing from the Visualization API to the Google Map API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed to google map api, insted og google viz api and everything worked grate.